# Probability of computer chips being defective?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, conditional-probability

> Out of 10 computer chips, four are defective.
> Find the following.
> If three chips are randomly chosen for testing (without replacement), compute the probability that at most 2 of them are defective.

Three scenarios possible, zero chips are defective. One chip is defective and lastly two chips are defective.
Using Combination Formula.

$$
C(n,k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$$
defective $=4 $

non defective $= 6$

Total Ways =$\binom{10}{3}$

X= $2 $ defective chips from $3 $ selected chips.

$$P(X\le2)=P(0)+P(1)+P(2)\\\frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}=.96667$$

Based on the above, would this be an appropriate way to solve the problem?

Comment: Looks good.  A simpler method might be to work from the complement.  The probability that all three are defective is $\binom 43\big /\binom {10}3=.0\overline 3$ which confirms your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lulu mentioned in the comment, it is easier to compute the complement. You can also solve an equivalent problem:

$3$ out of $10$ chips are used for test. If $4$ chips are randomly chosen to be defective, what is the probability that not all test chips are defective?

Once again, use complement: $1-\binom{7}{1}/\binom{10}{4}$